# Openlayers min-zoom to view all map

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

Hello I have a little problem with my openlayers map. If I zoom out I cant see small map picture and blank space. Like this.

[image]

I would like to set zoom, that minimum zoom would fill whole map on the screen.

Comment: you may need to set extent on `view` as map's bound coodinates or limit its minZoom

Comment: I would like to see that as one as for example google maps (one big map which fits whole DIV). How can I do it in my code please?

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274073/openlayers-min-zoom-to-view-all-map